# Как сделать что бы audio поток не прерывался ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

У меня есть ссылка на поток радио я её вставил в тег audio и оно проигрывает радио. Но иногда не хочет включатся или перестаёт играть. Приходится перезагружать страницу и пробовать снова. Как можно сделать проверка? Что бы проверяло, принимается ли поток, а если нет то отправляло запрос заново.

Comment: покажи свой код

Comment: кода как токового нет, просто тег audio и в src ссылка на поток

Comment: Всё что можно без кода получить так это ссылку на документацию:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AudioContext